# POST request in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, total.js

I'm new to Totaljs. I wrote a code which try to create user with PUT request with angular factory:

```
app.factory('User', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/register', null, {
        register: { method: 'post' }
    });
});
```

In my angular controller, when I click on register button this method run:

```
$scope.register = function() {
    $scope.user = new User({email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password});
    $scope.user.$register();
}
```

After click on register button, in console I got this :

> Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost.

This is my Totaljs controller:

```
exports.install = function(framework) {
    framework.route('/register', registerPage);
    framework.route('/register/', register, ['post']);
};

function registerPage() {
    var self = this;
    self.view('registerPage')
}

function register() {
    var self = this;
    console.log("run")
    // instead add new user I just return an existing user for test
    var User = MODEL('user').Schema

    User.find(function(err, docs) {
        self.json(docs);
    });

}
```

When I try it with jQuery's $.ajax It works fine! So what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: should it not be `$scope.user.register()` rather than `.$register()`?

Comment: No, That is correct!

Comment: Interesting, I've never called it that way on my `$resource`s

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works with $.ajax post but it not work with this code?

Comment: When I use $save instead my custom $register, server respond bad request!

Answer (score 0):

I ask my question from Peter Širka, he mail this answer:

> Hello,
>   it's ok. I found a problem in route:
>
> framework.route('/register', register, ['put', 'json']);

Comment: Framework supports multiple methods in one route. Example: `framework.route('/register/', register, ['put', 'post', 'json'])`. Thanks.